# What is wrong with my Preorder traversal?

Tags: java, recursion, tree-traversal, preorder

I am trying to solve this problem https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-preorder-traversal/ , i.e. preorder traversal with recursive slution.

EDIT: The whole code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution {

    public class TreeNode {
         int val;
         TreeNode left;
         TreeNode right;
         TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
    }
     static List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     public List<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
            if(root == null){
                return new ArrayList<Integer>();
            }
            res.add(root.val);
            if(root.left != null){
                res.add(preorderTraversal(root.left));
            }
            if(root.right != null){
                res.add(preorderTraversal(root.right));
            }
            return res;
      }
}
```

I have wrong answer because of the following:

```
Input:  {1,2}
Output:     [1,1,2]
Expected:   [1,2]
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

EDIT: I dont have `main()` method or unit tests. If you open the link that I posted you will see that this is **online judging system**.

Comment: This isn't your actual code. Post the code you're actually using. (copy-paste, don't retype)

Comment: I assume there is more code, a main/unit test or something. Can we see that?

Comment: No. You don't show how this input is used and how the output is created.

Comment: Using a `static` mutable `List` and returning it or something else from an _instance_ method smells very odd.

Comment: Your edit has done little more than combine what you showed us before into a single class and showed us your includes. Where is the main()/unit test?

Comment: This is an online judging system. This is all information that I have

Comment: Then I'm not really sure what to tell you. You've given us your tools, but you haven't told us how you've tried to use them. Based on what you've told me, I kind of have to assume that the missing code is correct, and since I don't see anything immediately and obviously wrong with the above...

Comment: @DavidFrye What more should I say? I gave you the link + my whole solution + the output that I receive from the system. If I've missed something, please tell me?

Comment: Yeah, I was so focused on what was missing that I didn't think about this carefully enough and missed an obvious problem. I apologize for being an idiot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that within each recursive loop, you are adding the entire array again into your final result.

For example, given the following tree:

```
  1
 /
2
```

Your first iteration adds 1 into 'res' variable.  The problem is when it gets to this line:

```
res.add(preorderTraversal(root.left));
```

Then it recursively calls itself for the left side.  That preorderTraversal will return the res array, which will be [1,2].  Hence, when [1,2] gets added to res (which was [1], remember?), then you get [1,1,2].

Here's code that should work:

```
public List<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if(root == null){
        return result;
    }

    result.add(root.val);
    if(root.left != null){
        result.addAll(preorderTraversal(root.left));
    }
    if(root.right != null){
        result.addAll(preorderTraversal(root.right));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for the help! I also tried this but I got `Time Limit`

Comment: I will try to solve it iteratively, I guess it was the idea of having time limit (i.e. avoiding "obvious" recursive solution). But once again thanks for the explanation!

Comment: It's probably `addAll` that's slow. Try implementing a helper method like `public void preorderTraversal(List<Integer> result, TreeNode root)`

Comment: Generating loads of `List` instances and adding them all together is probably costing you. You can pass the accumulator in the method signature - this is a common pattern in recursive code.

Comment: Yes, I agree with both fgb and Boris.  The code I put above works but does not have the best performance.  As they said, a helper method is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

For the left and right nodes, just call `preorderTraversal` recursively, and it will add the values to `res`. Calling `add/addAll` on `res` with the results of these recursive calls is wrong.

```
public class Solution {
     List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     public List<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
            if(root == null){
                return new ArrayList<Integer>();
            }
            res.add(root.val);
            if(root.left != null){
                preorderTraversal(root.left);
            }
            if(root.right != null){
                preorderTraversal(root.right);
            }
            return res;
      }
}
```

There's a little problem with this solution -- `res` retains the values from previous calls, so calling `preorderTraversal` more than once on the same instance may return incorrect results. Here's  a solution that does not have this drawback:

```
public class Solution {
     public List<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
            List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            preorderTraversal(root, res);
            return res;
      }
      private void preorderTraversal(TreeNode node, List<Integer> res) {
          if (node != null) {
              res.add(node.val);
              preorderTraversal(node.left, res);
              preorderTraversal(node.right, res);
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this method code:

```
public List<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
        if(root == null){
            return new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
        res.add(root.val);
        if(root.left != null){
            res = preorderTraversal(root.left);
        }
        if(root.right != null){
            res = preorderTraversal(root.right);
        }
        return res;
   }
```

btw, you were doing `res.add` in the recursion. You should rather do `res=` in it.

Comment: Duh. I was so focused on what was missing that I missed this. Nice :)

Comment: With this I have again Wrong answer with the same paramethers

Comment: What if root.left and root.right are both not null?

Answer (score 1):

**A working solution :**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



class TreeNode 
{
      int val;
     TreeNode left;
     TreeNode right;
     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 }

class Solution {
    public List<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) 
    {
       ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if(root == null)
            return res;
        else res.add(root.val);

        if(root.left != null)
        {
            res.add(root.left.val);
            preorderTraversal(root.left);
        }

        if(root.right != null)
        {
            res.add(root.right.val);
            preorderTraversal(root.right);
        }


        return res;    
    }
}

public class TreeTest
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Solution c = new Solution();

        TreeNode t1 = new TreeNode(1);
        TreeNode t2 = new TreeNode(2);
        TreeNode t3 = new TreeNode(3);

        //Link the nodes of the tree
        t1.left = t2;
        t1.right = t3;


        List<Integer> list = c.preorderTraversal(t1);

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not posted the whole code how the input is done and output is produced it is difficult to tell. For preorder traversal it should be something like this.

```
 void traverse(TreeNode node){
   if(node != null){
      res.add(node.val);
      traverse(root.left);
      traverse(root.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I posted a link + all the code that I have + the output from the system. So I dont have anything else to post. + this is an online system so there is a method signature and I have stick to it.

Comment: I got it. Try the code I posted. Since your 'res' variable is static so I dont think there is any need to return the same. Either stick to your signature and use code posted by others or use my code iof you want to keep 'res' as static.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<E> getPreOrderTraversal() {
    return getPreOrderTraversal(root);
}

private ArrayList<E> getPreOrderTraversal(Node tree) {
    ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();

    if (tree != null) {
        list.add((E) tree.value);
        list.addAll(getPreOrderTraversal(tree.left));
        list.addAll(getPreOrderTraversal(tree.right));
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A working and LeetCode accepted solution:

```java
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        return preOrderTraversalInternal(root, list);
    }
    private List<Integer> preOrderTraversalInternal(TreeNode root, List<Integer> list){
    if(root == null) return list;
    list.add(root.val);
    if(root.left != null){
      preOrderTraversalInternal(root.left, list);
    }
    if(root.right != null){
      preOrderTraversalInternal(root.right, list);
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that within each recursive loop, you are adding the entire array again into your final result.
You need to add left or right nodes only one time while traversing but in your code whole arr is getting added to the new res array.
This result will contain repetitive nodes.

For these issues, please use Print statements after every recursive call to debug the problem.

Solution -
Use addAll method:  res.addAll(node.left);