# Why is my preorder traversal returning an empty list?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, preorder

I am trying to understand why code is returning an empty list.
I am not looking for a solution to the problem.
The solution already exists in [What is wrong with my Preorder traversal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969599/what-is-wrong-with-my-preorder-traversal)

I want to understand, what is incorrect about my current understanding of recursion and the call stack upon using a global variable.

```
class Solution {
    ArrayList<Integer> list;
    public List<Integer> preorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        preOrder(root);
        return list;
    }
    public void preOrder(TreeNode node){
        System.out.println(list.toString());
        if(node == null)
            return;
        
        list.add(node.val);
        
        //System.out.println(list.toString());
        
        preorderTraversal(node.left);
        preorderTraversal(node.right);
    }
}
```

For the following tree : [1,null,2,3]

I notice that in the first print call
I get 7 empty lists

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

In my second print call, I get the following

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

Why isn't my global variable list not "saving" or "appending" to the next call stack?
It seems like, there are multiple list objects being utilized.

Comment: Hint: each time you call `preorderTraversal` your `list` gets wiped.

Comment: `list = new ArrayList<Integer>();` <- This will reassign your `list` variable to a newly created empty List object. So it is impossible that multiple calls of `preorderTraversal` "append" to the same list because you explicitly coded that method so that the first thing it does is create a brand new list

Comment: welp......... i understand....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use `preorderTraversal` with left and right nodes so each time it will override list value with a new empty list, you should use preOrder with left and right node like this

```java
public void preOrder(TreeNode node){
    if(node == null)
        return;
        
    list.add(node.val);
        
    preOrder(node.left);
    preOrder(node.right);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your answer, but the list inside preorderTraversal is local to this method and isn't defined.